# Open_basedir restriction oddness

Tags: php, open-basedir

I'm having a problem with [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) in PHP, with the returned error message telling me that the open_basedir restriction is in place (which I've set) and that on the path I'm attempting to write to is not within the allowed paths, but it is (and is clearly displayed on the error message).

Has anyone come across this before?

Edit:

Sorry, the error message might help!:

> Unhandled Error (/var/www/vhosts/(myhost)/libs/imanager.php, 226): 2,
>   '...move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]:
>   open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/var/www/vhosts/(myhost)/httpdocs/tributes/images/precrop/1317227884228.jpg)
>   is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/var/www/vhosts/(myhost)/httpdocs/tributes/images/precrop/:/tmp)...'

Answer (score 0):

Not come across this before. You can only use move_uploaded_file if the file you are trying to move was uploaded using PHP.
Try removing the trailing '/' from your precrop directory in the configuration.

There's some extra open_basedir information here:
http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2007/12/30/fixing-php-s-require-open_basedir-restri

Answer (score 0):

There is PHP bug (["Regression (5.3.3-5.3.4) in open_basedir with a trailing forward slash"](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53577)), that is triggered when `open_basedir` have trailing slash. As workaround remove trailing slash from path in `open_basedir`. This bug should be fixed in recent versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `open_basedir` will also fail if you have symlinks along the path. From http://php.net/open_basedir:

> All symbolic links are resolved, so it's not possible to avoid this restriction with a symlink.

Please check if `/var/www/vhosts/(yourhost)/httpdocs/tributes/images/precrop/` is a real directory path, not symlinked one.

Answer (score 0):

Some directory in the path does not exist.

e.g.

```ini
; php.ini
open_base_dir = /var/www/a/b/c
```

if you `move_uploaded_file('/var/www/a/b/c/d/1', $_FILES['x']['tmp_name'])`
and you only have `/var/www/a` but NOT `/var/www/a/b` then you will get the misleading

> `open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/a/b/c/d/1) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/a/b/c)'`

which is weird.

After you create all the paths mentioned in open_base_dir, but still lack some inner directory, let's say you now have `/var/www/a/b/c` but is lacking `/var/www/a/b/c/d`, the same line as above will generate the error

> `move_uploaded_file(/var/www/a/b/c/d/1): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in someScript.php:123`

which makes much more sense.

So, the answer to your problem: you are missing directories that are part of the open_base_dir path.